# Passing a generic argument in a C function

Tags: c

I have a struct

```
typedef struct
{  
    void *l_var;      
    void *r_var;    
}EXPR;

EXPR expr;
```

I initialize it

```
expr.l_var = &motor_rt_params[0].position;
expr.r_var = &motor_rt_params[1].position;
```

Now I want to operate with the values

```
void SCRIPT_Process(void *l_var, void *r_var, uint32_t oper)
{
    int32_t res;

    switch (oper)
    {
        case OP_PLUS: 
          res = *((??? *) l_var) + *((??? *)r_var);
          break;
        case OP_MINUS: 
          res = *((??? *) l_var) - *((??? *)r_var);
          break; 
    }
}

SCRIPT_Process(expr.l_var , expr.r_var , OP_PLUS);
```

The variables may be 32, 16, 8 bit.
The question - how can I cast it to an appropriate type (instead of (??? *)) in run time?

Comment: I think you need to have a rethink on the design of your code

Answer (score 2):

What about to also save the size when you initialize the pointers ?

```
typedef struct
{  
    void *l_var;      
    void *r_var;    
    size_t sz;
}EXPR;

expr.l_var = &motor_rt_params[0].position;
expr.r_var = &motor_rt_params[1].position;
expr.sz = sizeof(motor_rt_params[1].position);
```

allowing to to for instance

```
void SCRIPT_Process(void *l_var, void *r_var, size_t sz, uint32_t oper)
{
    int32_t res;

    switch (oper)
    {
        case OP_PLUS: 
          if (sz == sizeof(int32_t))
            res = *((int32_t *) l_var) + *((int32_t *)r_var);
          else /* suppose a int16_t */
            res = *((int16_t *) l_var) + *((int16_t *)r_var);
          break;
        case OP_MINUS: 
          if (sz == sizeof(int))
            res = *((int32_t *) l_var) - *((int32_t *)r_var);
          else /* suppose a int16_t */
            res = *((int16_t *) l_var) - *((int16_t *)r_var);
    }
}

SCRIPT_Process(expr.l_var , expr.r_var , expr.sz, OP_PLUS);
```

supposing it is *int* or *short* only, I let you adding the case of a `int8_t`

The advantage also placing the size in the EXPR is to not lost that information  / create inconsistencies by error because managed in different piece of code.

Or may be to give the EXPR rather than the fields separately in arguments to `SCRIPT_Process` ?

May be you also need to know if signed or unsigned, with an additional field, or using an *int* for the size valuing the positive size for unsigned (4, 2 or 1) and negative size for a signed (-4, -2 -1).

An other way is to save pointers to the right functions rather than the size, a kind of C++ virtual implementation.

Of course all of that supposes you cannot save values as `int32_t` in the struct and you really need to save the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

safe and the same generic. No pointer punning. The type list in the union might be much longer

```
typedef union
{
    int8_t u8;
    int16_t u16;
    int32_t u32;
}data_t;


int32_t get(data_t *o, int size)
{
    switch (size)
    {
        case 8: 
           return o -> u8;
          break;
        case 16: 
           return o -> u16;
          break; 
        default: 
          return o -> u32;
          break; 
    }
}

void SCRIPT_Process(data_t *l_var, data_t *r_var, uint32_t oper, int sizel, int sizer)
{
    int32_t res;
    int32_t l = get(l_var, sizel);
    int32_t r = get(r_var, sizer);


    switch (oper)
    {
        case OP_PLUS: 
          res = l + r;
          break;
        case OP_MINUS: 
          res = l -r;
          break; 
          /* ..... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. But  ''int size'' - I should retrieve it anyway? So any l_var or r_var hase to have its associated ''size'' variable ?

Comment: No there is no way

Comment: Why? If I add another variable and then expr.l_var = &motor_rt_params[0].position; epr.l_var_type = sizeof(motor_rt_params[0].position);
So then I can pass epr.l_var_type into int32_t get(data_t *o, int size)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the values in the `void*`, rather than their address:

```
expr.l_var = (void*)motor_rt_params[0].position;
expr.r_var = (void*)motor_rt_params[1].position;
```

Then to use them, cast to `intptr_t` (values, not pointers).  These types are guaranteed to be the same width as a pointer, so you won't need to care anymore about the width of the source values.

Comment: this way?  l_r_res = ((intptr_t)(in_expr.l_var)) - ((intptr_t)(in_expr.r_var)); It gives me a value at the pointer?

Comment: the problem is - void* on 32-bit machine is 32 bit by default. It wouldn't give me the right value on uint8_t variable.

Answer (score 0):

> The variables may be 32, 16, 8 bit.

So you need to know:

- variables addresses
- variables types and
- operation

And you need to pass that information along.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

enum type_e {
    TYPE_u8,
    TYPE_u16,
    TYPE_u32,
    // TODO: add more, ex. TYPE_INT, TYPE_DOUBLE, etc.
};

enum oper_e {
    OP_PLUS,
    OP_MINUS,
    // TODO: add mode, ex. OP_POW or OP_DIV etc. 
};

void SCRIPT_Process(void *res, const void *l, const void *r, enum type_e type, enum oper_e oper)
{
    switch (oper) {
    case OP_PLUS:
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_u8:
            *(uint8_t*)res = *(uint8_t*)l + *(uint8_t*)r;
            break;
        case TYPE_u16:
            *(uint16_t*)res = *(uint16_t*)l + *(uint16_t*)r;
            break;
        case TYPE_u32:
            *(uint32_t*)res = *(uint32_t*)l + *(uint32_t*)r;
            break;
        default:
            assert(0);
        }
        break;
     case OP_MINUS:
        // TODO:
        assert(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    uint32_t l = 5, r = 2, res;
    SCRIPT_Process(&res, &r, &l, TYPE_u32, OP_PLUS);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", (int)l, (int)r, (int)res);
}
```

Would be nice to provide a macro to make the code more verbose and with less typing:

```
#define SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(type, res, l, op, r) \
      *(type*)res = *(type*)l op *(type*)r;

void SCRIPT_Process(void *res, void *l, void *r, enum type_e type, enum oper_e oper)
{
    switch (oper) {
    case OP_PLUS:
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_u8:
            SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(uint8_t, res, l, +, r);
            break;
        case TYPE_u16:
            SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(uint16_t, res, l, +, r);
            break;
        case TYPE_u32:
            SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(uint32_t, res, l, +, r);
            break;
        default:
            assert(0);
        }
        break;
     case OP_MINUS:
        // TODO:
        assert(0);
    }
}
```

Or even more simple with more macros, which makes adding new operations and types trivial:

```
#define SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(type, res, l, op, r) \
      *(type*)res = *(type*)l op *(type*)r;

#define SCRIPT_PROCESS_TYPE_CASES(type, res, l, op, r) \
    switch (type) { \
    case TYPE_u8: SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(uint8_t, res, l, op, r); break; \
    case TYPE_u16: SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(uint16_t, res, l, op, r); break; \
    case TYPE_u32: SCRIPT_PROCESS_MACRO(uint32_t, res, l, op, r); break; \
    default: assert(0); break; \
    }

void SCRIPT_Process(void *res, void *l, void *r, enum type_e type, enum oper_e oper)
{
    switch (oper) {
    case OP_PLUS:
        SCRIPT_PROCESS_TYPE_CASES(type, res, l, +, r);
        break;
     case OP_MINUS:
        SCRIPT_PROCESS_TYPE_CASES(type, res, l, -, r);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you could even go with even more generic solution, having separate types for result, left and right operands:

```
   void SCRIPT_Process(
         void *res, enum type_e restype,
         const void *l, enum type_e ltype,
         const void *r, enum type_e rtype,
         enum oper_e oper) {
     if (restype == TYPE_u8 && ltype == TYPE_u32 && rtype == TYPE_u16 && oper == OP_ADD) {
           *(uint8_t*)res = *(uint32_t*)ltype + *(uint16_t*)rtype;
     } if ( // and so on so on so on so on ....
  }
```

Comment: So, in any case I should add a variable along with every pointer - 
uint32_t var_type = sizeof(my_current_var)?   
   
expr.l_var = &motor_rt_params[0].position;       
epr.l_var_type = sizeof(motor_rt_params[0].position);         

this way?

Comment: Yes, in a way, you need to pass all the information you need. In this case, you need a pointer to the variable and variable type, so yes. `sizeof` is the size of a variable, doesn't indicate it's type. For example, on my machine I can have `sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t)` or for example `sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(int)`. `sizeof` can be a simple trick, but it may fail you in the long run. If you aim to be really portable, don't depend on undefined behavior. But (and only "but"), if you only aim to support ex. 3 types `int{8,16,32}_t`, you can differentiate them using `sizeof`.

Comment: Trouble with macros it makes debugging a lot harder.

Comment: btw. `int8_t arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};  SCRIPT_Process(&arr[1],&arr[2],  ...);` and your incorrect pointer punning function will not work.

Comment: This function will work only in a very limited number of usage cases

Comment: How can I improve the function?

Comment: @john7 see my answer